# Classification of lists of word2vec vectors doesn't work

Tags: classification, neural-networks, word2vec, keras

I have 2 lists of word2vec vectors. First list has vectors, which represent fruits names, second list has vectors which represent vegetables names.

I am trying to train neural network on this 2 lists. Output for fruits is [1, 0] and output for vegetables is [0, 1]

Finally, when network will be trained, I want to feed word2vec vector of word "fruits" and receive output [1, 0]. And for "vegetables" I want receive output [0, 1].

But I have trouble: when network is training, accuracy index "freeze" at value 0.5

I use pre-trained "lexvec.enwiki+newscrawl.300d.W.pos.vectors" word2vec model with gensim, keras with Dense layers.

Here is NN model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=300, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(400, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(400, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse', metrics=["accuracy"])
```

What should I do to make my classification work?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to consider is the size of your training data. From your description and results I gather that it is small. There are three things your need to:

1. Change your loss to categorical crossentropy and use a single output since you have boolean classes.
2. Significantly decrease the size of your network. First try a single hidden layer with far fewer hidden units.
3. Split your data into training, validation, and test sets. If your dataset is small, use cross-fold validation.

I would recommend starting with this code (logistic regression):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=300, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])
```

If that fails, add a hidden layer:

```
model = Sequential()
H = 100
model.add(Dense(H, input_dim=300, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])
```

H is the hyper-parameter you'll have to tune. Try 50, 100, 150, 200, 300.

Now if your classes aren't balanced (not 50/50 fruits/veggies) you should look at other metrics such as precision, recall, and F1.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for answer. I've already solved my issue. The problem was that I forgot to remove pad_sequences call from my copypasted code.

Comment: Please heed this advice though as it should improve your results.