# How to classify words of specific 2 classes using neural network?

Tags: classification, neural-networks, word2vec

I have 2 lists of words. One list has fruits names. Another list has cities names. I'm transforming it  with word2vec and trying to classify resulting vectors. But it doesn't work.

Comment: What is meant by "doesn't work"? This would be easier to answer if you could include more details about what is actually happening

Comment: Also, is this the same question https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/267347/60613 ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to use the neural network in such a simple problem. Use K-nearest neighbor (KNN) instead. That is, for a test sample, find the word from your training set that its vector is nearest to the vector of the test word, and assign the class of this nearest training sample to the test sample. If you want to use neural networks, which I do not suggest, you should have many training data to avoid a complex neural network from overfitting.